# Insert node at beginning of LinkedList

Tags: c++, linked-list

My professor required we make a `LinkedList` class with a `bool add(in newEntry)` method.

Two things I'm questioning my choices on is the variable name `temporary` and instances of how to return `False` if it isn't successfully added. Or is simply not returning `True` is going to return something `False`?

Is there a better convention than calling the new Node `temporary`?

## LinkedList.h

```
#pragma once

struct Node {
   int data;
   Node* next;
};

class LinkedList {
protected:
   Node* m_head;
   int currentSize;

public:
   // constructor
   LinkedList();

   // destructor

   //getters

   // setters
   /** */
   bool add(int newEntry);

};
```

## LinkedList.cpp

```cpp
/**Creates a new Node (dynamically allocated) with data = newEntry, adds it to the front of the List, and increases currentSize by 1. Returns true if the new Node with newEntry was added successfully */
bool LinkedList::add(int newEntry)
{
   Node* temporary;
   temporary = new Node;
   temporary->data = newEntry;
   temporary->next = nullptr;

   if (m_head == nullptr) {
      m_head = temporary;
   }
   else {
      temporary->next = m_head;
      m_head = temporary;
   }
   this->currentSize++;
   
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the code to provide context?

Comment: What else should be included? I was mostly interested in the implementation. Do you want to see the `.h` as well?

Comment: We would need the `LinkedList` and `Node` class definitions/implementations, so we can provide a more in-depth review than a single function. Knowing how you constructed and wrote those classes is a huge help to reviewers.

Comment: Ok no problem, I've added the class and struct you requested.

Answer (score 2):

The linked list class definitely needs a destructor, otherwise we leak memory.

And it definitely needs a copy-constructor and assignment operator, to avoid nodes belonging to two or more lists.  They can be declared `= delete`, but do need to exist.

The `protected` members are a concern.  If we intend to subclass from `LinkedList` then we really need a `virtual` destructor.  However, I think in this case, it's better to make the members private (the default for `class` types).

Users shouldn't need to know about the type `Node`, so it can be a class internal to `LinkedList`.

We should initialise `m_head` and `currentSize` in the class; then the constructor can be `= default`.

It doesn't make sense for the size to be negative, so use an unsigned type for that.  `std::size_t` is the usual choice, as it should be able to represent any number of elements that can be created in our address-space.

---

There doesn't seem to be much point returning a `bool` from the `add()` member function, since we never return a false value (failures are reported using exceptions).

Get into the habit of using preincrement (`++x`) in preference to postincrement (`x++`) when the value doesn't matter.  For many types, the former is more efficient (can save copying objects).  There's no need to explicitly write `this->` when accessing member variables.

If we look at your `if`/`else`, we see that they share the last statement:

> ```
>    if (m_head == nullptr) {
>       m_head = temporary;
>    }
>    else {
>       temporary->next = m_head;
>       m_head = temporary;
>    }
> ```

So we can move `m_head = temporary` to the common code path after that:

```
   if (m_head == nullptr) {
   }
   else {
      temporary->next = m_head;
   }
   m_head = temporary;
```

Then observe that prior to this, we set `temporary->next` to null, but we only need to do this for the first branch above, since the `else` branch immediately overwrites:

```
   if (m_head == nullptr) {
      temporary->next = nullptr;
   }
   else {
      temporary->next = m_head;
   }
   m_head = temporary;
```

Now we see that if `m_head` is null, then setting `next` to `m_head` will set it to null:

```
   if (m_head == nullptr) {
      temporary->next = m_head;
   }
   else {
      temporary->next = m_head;
   }
   m_head = temporary;
```

Which we can then write as

```
   temporary->next = m_head;
   m_head = temporary;
```

So the whole function now becomes

```
void LinkedList::add(int newEntry)
{
   Node* temporary = new Node;
   temporary->data = newEntry;
   temporary->next = m_head;
   m_head = temporary;
   ++currentSize;
}
```

And we can use *aggregate initialization* to set those members in the new `Node` object:

```
void LinkedList::add(int newEntry)
{
   m_head = new Node{newEntry, m_head};
   ++currentSize;
}
```

This neatly solves the problem you asked about naming the new node - now it doesn't even have a name!

---

## Updated code

```
#include <cstddef>

class LinkedList
{
    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        Node* next;
    };

    Node* m_head = nullptr;
    std::size_t currentSize = 0;

public:
    LinkedList() = default;
    LinkedList(const LinkedList&) = delete;
    void operator=(const LinkedList&) = delete;
    ~LinkedList() noexcept;

    /** prepend the new value to the head of the list */
    void add(int newEntry);

};
```

```
LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
    Node *current = m_head;
    while (current) {
        Node *next = current->next;
        delete current;
        current = next;
    }
}

void LinkedList::add(int newEntry)
{
    m_head = new Node{newEntry, m_head};
    ++currentSize;
}
```

Comment: Ooo I love that and I learned a lot. Thank you Toby.

Comment: Thanks for the typo fix @Deduplicator - I fixed it in one place but missed the other!

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would go for newElement, but that's mainly because I can't spell "temporary".  If you added a constructor to `Node`, you could create the new value more elegantly:

```
Node (const int nData = 0, const Node* pNext = nullptr)
  : data(nData), next(pNext)
{}


m_head = new Node (newEntry, m_head);
if (m_head) {
   this->currentSize++;
   return true;
}
return false;
```

The chances of ever returning false are incredibly slim, and if it does happen, then you have more trouble than an error message will help with.

Comment: `m_head` cannot be false after we've assigned the new `Node` pointer to it.  (Perhaps you're thinking of `std::malloc()` which reports failure in a different way to `new`?)

Comment: You don't need to write a constructor for Node like that - aggregate initialisation will work fine unless you're stuck with an ancient standards version (i.e. < C++11).  Which you shouldn't be, especially as a learner.